# jquery add delay on hover-out animation only if previous animation is complete

Tags: jquery, css, delay, jquery-animate

I have a small `jQuery` snippet which animates an image caption, based on the image's `alt` attribute if it exists.

It's working fine but I have one small issue. I want a `delay` on the hover out (`slideUp`) animation, but **only** if the previous `slideIn` animation **completed fully**. In basic scenarios:

**scenario 1:** User hovers over image, caption fully animates in. User hovers out, animation delays (caption stays put) for 2 seconds, then animates out.

**scenario 2:** User hovers over image, caption begins to animate in, but user hovers out before it completed. Animation should immediately stop and animate out **without** delay.

Scenario 1 works perfectly. scenario 2 doesn't. The delay happens on the partially animated elements before it slides out which isn't desired. I can see the flaw in my code, but can't seem to figure out how to address it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4bzE/9/), and current script:

```
$('.pv-inner').hover(function() {

    var img = $(this).find('img:first');
    var text = img.attr('alt');

    if (text !== undefined) {
        //remove any existing captions
        $(this).find('.kppImageCaption').remove();

        //insert the new caption
        img.after('<div class="kppImageText">' + text + '</div><div class="kppImageCaption"></div>');

        //animate it in
        $(this).find('.kppImageCaption').stop().slideDown('slow').animate({
            opacity: 0.6
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 'slow',
            complete: function() {
                $(this).parent().find('.kppImageText').fadeTo(1000, 1);
            }
        });
    }
}, function() {

    //on hover out animate it out. Here is the problem. I only want the delay 
    //to occur if the above hover over animation completed - currently it delays
    //in all cases.
    $(this).find('.kppImageCaption, .kppImageText').stop().delay(2000).slideUp('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

**EDIT**:

[Final working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4bzE/11/). May help someone down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create variable, let's call it `var animationStatus = false`
Just before starting animating it it, set `animationStatus = true`

in `complete` function (see jQuery animate docs) set `animationStatus = false`

In your function which is responsible for hiding - create if statement. If animationStatus === false - delay. If animationStatus === true - without delay.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I'll try this - if I have multiple images on a page using this script, I'm assuming they will share that variable though? I'm brutal with scope in js. Was also thinking of using/detecting a css class as a flag..

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used the same approach you suggested, but with a css class flag to ensure js scope wouldn't be a problem if I have multiple images with captions on a page. Final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r4bzE/11/

Comment: Happy to hear that :) That is also why I am trying to explain an idea instead of providing a working solution (code). Love to see how people do it by themselves :)